# Searching Excel cell for First Number and Copying all Words before that.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of entries that is a mix of words, letters, and numbers. I want to only copy the words that happen before the first number.

`Term Loan`
`Subordinated, 10% due 6/23/2020`
`Subordinated Debt (Interest Rate 12.00%,  Maturity Date Due 2/15/19)`
`One stop (10.01%, Due 12/1/18)`
`Second Lien Term Loan to CP Well Testing, LLC (9.00% (LIBOR + 7.00% with 2.00% LIBOR floor) plus 9.00% PIK, due 4/1/2019)`
(`Prime Plus 2%, Current Coupon 5.25%, Secured Debt (Maturity - November 14, 2013)`)

The formula I'm trying to think of would return:

`Term Loan`
`Subordinated`
`Subordinated Debt`
`One Stop`
`Seccond Lien Term Loan to CP Well Testing, LLC`
(`Secured Debt`)

I know that if I searched for the first number, the results would include some unwanted parentheses, and maybe some extra words--especially in that last case--but this was the best I could think of to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  If your string is in cell A1, =LEFT(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))-1)

I borrowed the search formula from ExtendOffice, below.  It hard codes an array to search for with the curly brackets (type them, don't hit control enter), and uses the concatenated numbers so that none of the searches return an error.  If you don't have any numbers, it returns the position of the concatenated 0, and therefore you get your whole string.

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2510-excel-find-first-last-number-in-string.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy question to answer, and this is not really a complete answer. Hopefully you can use this as a starting point for a better solution. Your data is not in an easily usable format. As you pointed out it is a mix of words, letters and numbers.

This formula works for everything but the final line: `=MID(A3,1,IFERROR(FIND("(",A3)-1,IFERROR(FIND(",",A3)-1,LEN(A3))))`. Basically I first go looking for an open parenthesis and that works most of the time as the the end of the word you are looking for. If there isn't a "(" then I look for a comma. If there isn't either then just use the whole word that is there.

You could add to my formula to get it to work for the final case too, but I recommend trying to fix the starting data instead.